# Better Adblocking in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I've tried Ad thwart and AdBlock in Google chrome, but neither of them provides ad blocking with a code (like in AdBlock plus on firefox). Suppose, If I want to block getclicky code or google analytics code on a web page, it is not possible.

Can I get this option using some extension in Chrome?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking with a code"?

Comment: Is [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) anything like what you seek? I suspect not but you can block Google Analytics for example.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need wait for sometime to get better version -> Recently Adthwart was taken over by Adblock plus(firefox guys) developers -> [Find More Details Here](http://adblockplus.org/blog/adblock-plus-for-google-chrome-to-be-released-soon).

Comment: Ya, Heard about it and that is one of the primary reasons on why I decided to move from Firefox to Chrome. But still, ad thwart doesn't have that ability to block code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more involved to set up and use, but [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) provides ad-blocking for everything in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly by "block code", but Google chrome can block ressources from downloading, if that's what you are after.

Everybody used to complain about this missing feature in the Chrome version of Adblock, but it's been there for almost a year now.

- [Slashdot article](http://apple.slashdot.org/story/10/07/20/0421257/Google-Chrome-Now-Has-Resource-Blocking-Adblock)
- [more on the chromium bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35897#c63)
- [Adblock for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)